# Envio de notificações do Sandbox do PagSeguro para o endereço local (C# ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, http

Estou realizando a integração do PagSeguro em um ambiente ASP.NET, e estava tudo ocorrendo bem até chegar na parte do envio de notificações do PagSeguro. Como vocês podem ver na imagem abaixo, eu configurei os seguintes parâmetros para redirecionamento e para notificações:
[image: Configuração de endereço para recebimento de notificação de transação]

Os parâmetros envolvendo o redirecionamento funcionaram corretamente, com o código da transação sendo enviado corretamente e o comprador sendo redirecionado para minha página. Entretanto, na hora de modificar o status da transação e a notificação ser enviada para o endereço configurado, nada ocorre, com o método sequer sendo chamado. Quando verifico o Log, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

[image: Log do PagSeguro]

Para receber as notificações, eu tentei utilizar os métodos como exibidos nas imagens a seguir:

[image: Método 1]

[image: Método 2]

[image: Método 3]

Entretanto, nenhum deles funcionou, com o Sandbox sequer chamando os mesmos.

A documentação relacionada ao recebimento de notificação está nesse link: https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/documentacao/pagamento-online/notificacoes/api-de-notificacoes#notificacoes-de-transacoes

Alguém saberia a solução ou poderia me indicar onde estou errando?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: O que acontece é que o pagseguro não consegue acessar o endereço localhost:50711, você terá que utilizar algum client tipo o Postman para simular a requisição POST do pagseguro.

Comment: Você testou pelo Chrome?

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas Você está correto. Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

Estou tendo este problema também para enviar notificações para o meu **localhost** quando clico no botão "**Reenviar notificação**", mas acho que é normal esse tipo de notificação não funcionar em **localhost**.

No meu caso, para funcionar o envio de notificações, eu envio elas através do botão "**Reenviar notificação local**".

Faça um teste e veja se você consegue receber a notificação local.

Caso apareça essa mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

veja se no canto direito do campo de URL está com esse símbolo:

[image]

Se estiver, clique nele e selecione "**Carregar scripts não seguros**" e tente enviar novamente a notificação local.